# Create and deploy apps using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, office-365

I want to build and deploy apps to office 365 preview site using visual studio 2012. Can any one point me some good help links? I have office/sharepoint templates installed in vs2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find a nice tutorial 
[Introducing “Napa” - Office 365 Development Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/07/17/introducing-napa-office-365-development-tools.aspx)

and [Introducing the new Office cloud app model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/07/17/introducing-the-new-office-cloud-app-model.aspx)

and [SharePoint & Office 2013 Developer tools for Visual Studio 2012 (link)…look in the Tools section.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123627)

Also msdn contains some nice training video's developing 
[Sharepoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/fp123633)

This wil help you get started.

Comment: I have not installed sharepoint 2013 server/foundation 2013. Will I be able to develope apps for office 365?

Comment: With vs 2012 it must be possible. But myself i did not try it

Comment: "Hello, world!" has never been harder :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great link to get you started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179930(v=office.15)

You can also find many other resources just by searching with the keywords in your question here.